# Don't close as a duplicate if the duplicate doesn't work for the OP

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, duplicate

This question:

[How can I add new keys to a keyring without hurting my fingernails?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/1837/how-can-i-add-new-keys-to-a-keyring-without-hurting-my-fingernails)

Has been closed as a duplicate of this:

[How can I (painlessly) add/remove keys to my key ring?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/139/how-can-i-painlessly-add-remove-keys-to-my-key-ring)

Now from the titles, that seems fine - they are clearly the same question. And the body agrees, he wants to do the same as the other person - add keys to keyrings.

However, there is something important here - he wants a solution that is *different* to the current ones.

> I saw some suggestions to use a staple remover, but that's not something I've ever owned or had a need for, so I don't want to buy one specially.

So the method that has been suggested **does not answer his question**. Now that's fine - not all questions do work for everyone, but that is no reason to stop them asking for other solutions. Let's look at the duplicate banner:

> marked as duplicate by [Zach Saucier](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/users/78/zach-saucier), [liebs19](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/users/27/liebs19), [J. Musser](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/users/25/j-musser), [Door Handle](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/users/49/door-handle), [michaelpri](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/users/20/michaelpri) 21 hours ago
>
> This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please [ask a new question](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

### If those answers do not fully address your question, ask a new question.

Why are we stopping them from asking a new question when the original? The duplicate banner itself is telling us that it was wrong to close it. I'm glad that this site has got a scope and may survive, but now it has gone over the top. We are closing questions that follow SE's rules (he has explained why the other question was not suitable) and our rules perfectly (It has a what I tried and why other solutions are not acceptable).

Comment: My main issue with this (in the scope of this site) is that if I find a nice "hack" to add keys to my keyring, I don't know where to put it if there are two questions. Answering both with the same hack seems wrong to me, and answering only one fragments knowledge.

Comment: This is basically saying I don't like the accepted answer on this other question so I'll ask a new one saying that it won't work while ignoring all other answers posted to this question.

Comment: He isn't ignoring all the other answers! There are only 2 other answers - and one says the same thing as the accepted one - staple remover. In fact, he mentions that answer as what he is doing now...

Comment: Allowing new questions that only disallow the top answer of previous questions asking the same thing is a terrible practice

Answer (score 10):

In this specific example I'd still consider it a duplicate.

**Problem 1: They're asking for the same result.**

If I were to answer the newer question, that answer would also be applicable to the older question, no? If answers to either question can be given to both, then [that's a pretty sure sign that it's a duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/12184/245709).

**Problem 2: They're ignoring other answers.**

They use the accepted solution of the other question as the unacceptable solution in the "What have you tried" section, but what about the other two solutions? Since questions can receive multiple *different* solutions, why not put a bounty on the question to get more answers rather than asking a new question?

**The Duplicate Banner.**

> This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question.

Note the word "Fully" in the banner. That means that in order for your question to be different, every answer to that question can't be applicable to your question.

The duplicate banner assumes that if none of the answers are applicable, then it's possible that your situation could be different, in which case you should ask a question about your specific situation. That's not necessarily true all the time, but it's a good indicator.

In this situation, it hasn't been explained why none of the answers on the original questions can't apply, so it's still a duplicate.

**Side Notes.**

Rather than creating noise and asking a new question, a bounty should be placed on the existing one to attract different answers (Just because you don't like the answers on a question doesn't mean you can ask it again).

I think it's going to be rare where people are going to ask for the same solution but have different situations where multiple variations of the question isn't going to be a duplicate.

If we allow people to ask new questions, with the accepted answer from a previous question as the qualifier, we're just going to have a lot of bad questions on the site. Eventually you're going to have a question that doesn't want one of the solutions given in another question, that doesn't want a solution given in another question, but receives the same answer as the first question that was unacceptable to the second question, which is all rather pointless as you could just have all the answers in the first question.

Comment: Couldn't agree more, the other questions has other answers besides the staple remover. Should they all be posted on the new question to see if they could be accepted there? I don't think this is what we want to happen.

Comment: It has 3 answers. 2 say the same thing (staple remover). The third is saying "use a key to prize it apart". He says he tried that, and it was unsatisfactory (and I agree).

Comment: @Tim The top-voted answer also mentions using a coin.

Comment: Okay, but he has said that of the 3 options presented to him, 2 are not solving his problem. Why are you ignoring the duplicate banner?

Comment: @Tim See my linked discussion on Meta Stack Exchange: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/12184/245709

Comment: Some questions are duplicates. Some aren't. This one is, but the original *does not solve his problem* (he said that). So it doesn't get closed.

Comment: @Tim So why can't he put a bounty on the original to get different answers?

Comment: He can. But we shouldn't be forcing him to do that - he is perfectly entitled to ask that question.

Comment: @Tim That's where we disagree then.

Comment: Okay. It appears that it isn't just you disagreeing, so I will go with the community consensus. However, **I do still think this is the wrong decision for this Q**.

Comment: @Tim So by this logic, could I reask every question with an accepted answer and just say that the accepted answer isn't what I wasn't because I don't have that thing?

Comment: @liebs Well the point of a life hack is to use whatever you have. If the materials specified in the answer are unavailable then yes.

Comment: If your reasoning were the community-accepted one, @Tim, I think that would be a very clear indicator that the SE model won't work for lifehacks.